# Shell script in autorun directory does not run when I log in

Tags: autorun

Using Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, I wrote this simple shell script and put it in `/usr/local/bin/MiddleClick.sh` Shell script in autorun directory does not run when I log in.that enables me to middle click by pressing the left and right click buttons on my keyboard simultaneously ,

```
#!/bin/bash
#Script file for activating middle click on keyboard.
xinput set-prop 10 "Evdev Middle Button Emulation" 1
```

It works just fine when when I run the script from the terminal, but I want this script to run automatically after I log in. I wrote the following .desktop file in `/home/user_name/.config/autostart/MiddleClick.desktop`,

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/local/bin/MiddleClick.sh
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=MiddleClick
Name=MiddleClick
Comment[en_US]=Script to enable middle click on keyboard
Comment=Script to enable middle click on keyboard
```

After I log in, the middle click feature is not activated, but if I run the script from the terminal, it gets activated.

As a test, I did this same procedure to run the command `firefox`. The Firefox web browser launches just fine automatically after I log in.

What could I be doing wrong? I'll appreciate the help you can give me!

Comment: Probably try finding the full path of the `xinput` executable by running `which xinput` and use it in your script like so `/usr/bin/xinput set-prop 10 "Evdev Middle Button Emulation" 1`

Comment: @Raffa Well, that didn't solve the problem, but it was worth a try. Thanks!